# Calculator with math.round with 2 decimal

Tags: javascript

I have to put online a calculator for a client and I facing a problem with the math.round.
Here is my code :

```
function calc(type){

    if(type == "terre"){

        var lo = parseFloat(document.getElementById("terre_lo").value);

        var la = parseFloat(document.getElementById("terre_la").value);

        var pr = parseFloat(document.getElementById("terre_pr").value);

        var res = lo * la * (pr / 12) / 27;

        document.getElementById("terre_re").innerHTML = Math.round(res * 100) / 100;

        tmp = Math.round(res * 100)/100;

        paillis = Math.round((res *30) /100) + res;

        if(tmp < (res * 0.30)/100){

            paillis;
        }

        document.getElementById("res_paillis").innerHTML = paillis;
    }
}

</script>
```

Every thing is working fine but I need to do the math for 30% of the result and round it with 2 decimals. Like this 1.32.
My problem is that it rounding it the same as the first result with small values.
I have to calculate the width (foot) x length(foot) x depth(inch)
Than I have to take this result + 30%.
With small value it round it the same as the result.
I'm not a programmer, am a web designer, so be comprehensive ;)

You can see the calculator page here [pepiniereduvieuxmoulin.com/services](http://pepiniereduvieuxmoulin.com/services)
Thank for the help

Comment: unable to understand your problem...please explain with an example

Comment: Ok. I have to calculate the lengh x width x depth for cubic yard result. Its for concrete. Then I have to add 30% of the result. So let say 2 foot x 3 foot x 12 inches = 0.22. Then I calculate 30% of .22 +0.22 = 0.22 !! Normaly, it should be 0.29 but it give me 0.22. If I take larger numbers, its is working.

Comment: I'm expecting that the result would be more precise. If I calculate it with manually it give me 0.286 as a result. Not 0.22.

Comment: I wish that the result would be 0.29

Comment: That was the calculator in the old site and it working well. http://pepinierenotredame.com/services/calculateur-terreau

Comment: When you Math.round `(res*30)/100` it becomes `0`, and `0 + .22` equals `.22`.

Comment: Kevin B RULES. At least much more than me. I'm felling stupid now. Thank you very much Kevin B

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
  function calc(type){

                if(type == "terre"){

                    var lo = parseFloat(document.getElementById("terre_lo").value);

                    var la = parseFloat(document.getElementById("terre_la").value);

                    var pr = parseFloat(document.getElementById("terre_pr").value);

                    var res = lo * la * (pr / 12) / 27;

                    document.getElementById("terre_re").innerHTML = Math.round(res * 100) / 100;

                        tmp = Math.round(res * 100)/100;

                        paillis = (res *30) /100 + res;

                        if(tmp < (res * 0.30)/100){

                            paillis;
                        }
                       document.getElementById("res_paillis").innerHTML = Math.round(paillis*100)/100;
```